# How to tag Realms of Arkania: Blade of Destiny

Tags: discussion, support

How do we tag [Realms of Arkania: Blade of Destiny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realms_of_Arkania:_Blade_of_Destiny)? There is already a question asked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153306/how-can-i-use-the-hetman-authorisation-in-realms-of-arcania-blade-of-destiny) without any tag.

Comment: How about `arkania-blades-of-destiny`?

Comment: Am I missing something or is it 'blade' not 'blades'?

Comment: @Vaishali - edited to reflect that, looks like Resorath has already edited the question